# Example request: seriously deficient homogeneous spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ac.commutative-algebra, cohomology, examples, homogeneous-spaces

In [a previous post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/231379/a-dimension-condition-on-the-cohomology-of-a-homogeneous-space), I cite a dimension condition commonly satisfied by homogeneous spaces and claim that a counterexample must have deficiency at least $3$. For convenience, I reproduce the definition of deficiency in the next paragraph.

Let $G/K$ be a homogeneous space with $K$ connected. The quotient map $G \to G/K$ induces a ring map $H^*(G/K) \to H^*(G)$ in rational cohomology whose image is an exterior algebra $\Lambda \hat P$. The dimension of $\hat P$ is bounded above by $\mathrm{rk \,}G - \mathrm{rk \,}K$, and the *deficiency* is the difference from this upper bound:
$$\mathrm{df}(G/K) := \mathrm{rk \,}G- \mathrm{rk \,}K - \dim_{\mathbb Q} \hat P.$$

Now one thing that is clear about deficiency is that it is additive in the sense that given two homogeneous spaces $G_1/K_1$ and $G_2/K_2$, one has
$$\mathrm{df}\Big(\frac{G_1 \times G_2}{K_1 \times K_2}\Big) = \mathrm{df}(G_1/K_1) + \mathrm{df}(G_2/K_2).$$ 
Morally, this is an uninteresting way of picking up deficiency, and particularly, it is not useful in constructing counterexamples to the dimension condition of the previous post. Call a homogeneous space $G/K$ *reducible* if it admits a direct product factorization in terms of other homogeneous spaces.

*All examples of irreducible homogeneous spaces that I know of from the literature are of deficiency $0$ or $1$.* I have been able to construct high-deficiency irreducible examples by modifying reducible ones, but these examples have a feel of cheapness to them and wind up satisfying the dimension condition anyway.

**Is anyone aware of any examples in the literature of irreducible homogeneous spaces of deficiency at least $2$?**

Answer (score 2):

def=2: see investigation of the case def=2 in [On coset-spaces of compact Lie groups by subgroups of corank 2. A.N.Shchetinin. Russian Mathematics, volume 61, pages 60–68(2017)]
and other papers of this author.